CondaSSLError when installing packages and creating virtual environment
When I was using Anaconda to install tensorflow on Linux server yesterday, I found that I cannot update, install, uninstall packages as well as create new conda environment. All of them returned the same error when collecting package metadata:
(base) user@servername:~$ conda update conda
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): \ Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: EE certificate key too weak (_ssl.c:1006)'))': /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json

failed

CondaSSLError: Encountered an SSL error. Most likely a certificate verification issue.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/linux-64/repodata.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: EE certificate key too weak (_ssl.c:1006)')))


FYI, I am a temporary user of the server, and I cannot use sudo. And I cannot use pip because it also needs sudo to install. I’m using Anaconda 24.1.2 and ubuntu 20.04.3.
Everything works fine before yesterday. Here are some approaches I tried to solve the problem:

I connected to the server with and without VPN (the one that bypass internet cencorship), but it showed no difference.
I deleted and installed Anaconda a few times but not working.
Switched to Tsinghua mirror repository and still no difference. My .condarc file is as follows. Since there’s no difference, I changed back to the default repository.

channels:
- https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/linux-64
- https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/linux-64
show_channel_urls: true



I specified my ssl certificate according to KWA
But still, the error stayed the same.
Then, I tried to set ssl_verify to false by conda config --set ssl_verify False. The error message was changed to UnicodeDecoderError. The detailed error report is as follows.

(base) user@servername:~$ conda update conda
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 17, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
...

                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/gateways/repodata/__init__.py", line 858, in fetch_latest
        raw_repodata = self.cache_path_json.read_text()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/pathlib.py", line 1059, in read_text
        return f.read()
               ^^^^^^^^
      File "<frozen codecs>", line 322, in decode
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 465: invalid continuation byte



I tried cleaning the cache by conda clean --all
I specified the encoding method by export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
The above two methods didn’t change the error report. Then, I reached the file /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/pathlib.py and changed the decoding method in the original file from

   def read_text(self, encoding=None, errors=None):
        """
        Open the file in text mode, read it, and close the file.
        """
        encoding = io.text_encoding(encoding)
        with self.open(mode='r', encoding=encoding, errors=errors) as f:
            return f.read()


to (also tried “latin-1” )
    def read_text(self, encoding="gbk", errors=None):
        """
        Open the file in text mode, read it, and close the file.
        """
        encoding = io.text_encoding(encoding)
        with self.open(mode='r', encoding=encoding, errors=errors) as f:
            return f.read()


It returns the error
(base) user@servername:~$ conda update conda
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 17, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
...
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda_libmamba_solver/index.py", line 337, in _load_channels
        info = self._json_path_to_repo_info(url, jsons[url])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/conda_libmamba_solver/index.py", line 293, in _json_path_to_repo_info
        repo = api.Repo(self._pool, noauth_url, str(path_to_use), escape_channel_url(noauth_url))
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    RuntimeError: Unable to read repodata JSON file 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64', error was: repository does not start with an object


Are there any other methods to enable my conda to install packages and create virtual environment? Any insights will be appreciated. Thanks a lot!
As I stated before, I'd like to use my conda to install and uninstall packages and create virtual environment as usual.
